# PLSQL Insert special character values into table from a Select

Tags: plsql

I am using a select withing an insert to add a previous record value. This requires me to do the following code:

```
insert into My_table 
values ('a', select value_with_sp_char from table where criterion_to_guarantee_single_row=true), 'b','c')
```

Now whenever the value_with_sp_char has a character like _,&,%,.,comma,- the query fails.

Any ideas on how I can get that value inserted correctly?

Comment: please provide table schema,  error message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, I solved this.

I was not entirely truthful in the way I have represented this question.

I was trying to add the value to a variable like so

```
Declare
    lv_txt_var varchar2(255) := '';
Begin
    select value_with_sp_char into lv_txt_var from table where criterion_to_guarantee_single_row=true;
if (input_param = null)
    insert into table values ('a', lv_txt_var, 'b', 'c');
end if;
```

when I used the above query, that failed because of the special char. However, when I modified this to use the select query, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need PL/SQL for this insert. It's better to write it this way:

```
INSERT INTO table_a
SELECT 'a', value_with_sp_char, 'b', 'c'
FROM   table_b
WHERE  criterion_to_guarantee_single_row = true;
```